# Strip new line characters within a quoted string in unix

Tags: unix, newline

I have a text file that goes like this:

```
abc 123 xyz
"abc
123" xyz
```

I want to replace new lines with a space (' ') if the new line occurs within a quoted string. So I want output:

```
abc 123 xyz
abc 123 xyz
```

Is there a way to write a program in Unix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print a new line or just a space depending on how many `"` how got so far. This way, new line will just be printed if we are closing quotes.

```
$ awk '{n=split($0,a,"\""); val+=(n-1); gsub("\"",""); printf "%s%s", $0, (val%2?" ":"\n")}' file
abc 123 xyz
abc 123 xyz
```

#### Explanation

- `n=split($0,a,"\"")` count how many `"` appear in the current line. As `split()` returns how many pieces based on `"` as delimiter, at least we get a value of `1`.
- `val+=(n-1)` keep track of the balance. `-1` to just count the number of quotes, as split returns one more than needed.
- `gsub("\"","")` remove double quotes in the string.
- `printf "%s%s", $0, (val%2?" ":"\n")` print the line together with a space or a new line. If `val` is multiple of 2, new line; otherwise, space.

#### Test

Another example:

```
$ cat a
abc 123 xyz
"abc
hee
123" xyz
and "this
is not everything"
$ awk '{n=split($0,a,"\""); val+=(n-1); gsub("\"",""); printf "%s%s", $0, (val%2?" ":"\n")}' a
abc 123 xyz
abc hee 123 xyz
and this is not everything
```

Comment: Thanks...can you elaborate why we do: 'If val is multiple of 2, new line'

Comment: Sure, @Victor This is to check how balanced are the double quotes. `val` knows how many double quotes appeared so far. If it is 1, 3... it needs another one to close the quoted sentence. If it is 2, 4... it means that the sentence is already quoted, so it can print the new line.