# Tell awk to ignore line breaks in fields

Tags: linux, awk

Is it possible to tell awk to ignore line breaks in fields?
I have a file with line breaks in the middle of fields. To make it more complicated, fields can be, or not, enclosed by quotes.

```
id;code;description
1;a;"blablala"
2;b;"blablabla"
3;c;"a very long description with
line breaks
4;d;"blablabla"
```

I've tried, and failed:

```
awk -F";|[\".*\";]" '{print NF, "     ", $1,$2,$3,$4}' awk-test.txt

5       1 a  blablala
5       2 b  blablabla
4       3 c  a very long description with
1       line breaks
5       4 d  blablabla
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: try `awk -F";|[\".*\";]" 'NF{print NF, "     ", $1,$2,$3,$4}' file`

Comment: i think the field separator should be `-F"[;\"]"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I want it to ignore the line break after 'with'. It should count 4 lines with 5 fields each.

Comment: @user3748908 take a look at [Strip new line characters within a quoted string in unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428540/strip-new-line-characters-within-a-quoted-string-in-unix/25429287#25429287) It may help.

Comment: This is not a habit you want to get into. If at all possible, circle back to the source of your data and find an option to  turn off the line breaks. Are you using isql? then look at the man page for the option to set line length and set it to 100000! ;-) Same idea for other export tools Good luck!

Comment: @user3748908 Have you tried my script? Does it work as you expect?

Comment: @user3748908 Is it certain that no split field might contain the field separator? In the example, we can assume the ";" character will not be found in the description field, cannot we?

Comment: Do you miss closing `"` on your multiline example?

Answer (score -1):

You could use something along these lines:

```
BEGIN { FS = "[;\"]+" }
NR>1 && NF>1 { for(i=1; i<=cols; ++i) printf "%s%s" a[i], (i<cols?OFS:ORS) }
NF>1 { cols = split($0, a); next }
{ a[cols] = a[cols] $0 }
END { for(i=1; i<=cols; ++i) printf "%s%s" a[i], (i<cols?OFS:ORS) }
```

The general idea is that the continued lines are added to the final element of the array `a`. When a new record begins, the previous array is printed. The `END` block prints the contents of the last line.

```
$ awk -f line.awk file
id code description 
1 a blablala 
2 b blablabla 
3 c a very long description with line breaks
4 d blablabla
```